# iOS 9 Search Api - Is it required that using web markup api for public indexing?

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-searchapi

I understand from the iOS9 Search API WWDC video, using NSUserActivity with public indexing enabled can make that activity globally available if it exceeds some threshold. I wonder that is it possible to show any indexed user activity data at core spotlight search results to ALL iOS9 users with using only NSUserActivity with public indexing. Or is it **required** that also using Web Markup API for enabling to all iOS9 users?

Answer (score 1):

NSUserActivity is enough for publicly indexing your content. Although web markup also publicly indexes the content, but it is not a requirement.

For both NSUserActivity and Web Markup, threshold must be satisfied for public indexing.